# How to refactor semantic duplication

Tags: go, refactoring

I have defined two funcs that do slightly different things but are syntactically the same.

Functions in question send `POST` requests to an api.

The duplication occurs in constructing the request, adding headers, etc.

How can I refactor the code to remove said duplication.

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httputil"
)

type token struct {
    Token string
}

type config struct {
    Foo string
}

func main() {
    token, err := getAuthToken()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    config, err := getConfig("foo", token)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    _ = config
}

func getAuthToken() (string, error) {
    endpoint := "foo"

    body := struct {
        UserName string `json:"username"`
        Password string `json:"password"`
    }{
        UserName: "foo",
        Password: "bar",
    }

    jsnBytes, err := json.Marshal(body)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err

    }

    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", endpoint, bytes.NewReader(jsnBytes))
    if err != nil {
        return "", fmt.Errorf("Unable to create request. %v", err)

    }

    req.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")

    dump, err := httputil.DumpRequest(req, true)
    if err != nil {
        return "", fmt.Errorf("Could not dump request. ", err)
    }

    log.Println("Request: ", string(dump))

    client := http.Client{}
    log.Println("Initiating http request")

    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        return "", fmt.Errorf("HTTP Error: %v", err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    bytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        return "", fmt.Errorf("Error reading response body: %v", err)
    }

    var token token

    err = json.Unmarshal(bytes, &token)
    if err != nil {
        return "", fmt.Errorf("Could not unamrshal json. ", err)
    }

    return token.Token, nil
}

func getConfig(id string, token string) (*config, error) {
    endpoint := "foo"

    body := struct {
        ID string `json:"id"`
    }{
        ID: id,
    }

    jsnBytes, err := json.Marshal(body)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", endpoint, bytes.NewReader(jsnBytes))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("Unable to create request. %v", err)
    }

    req.Header.Add("Authorization", "Bearer "+token)
    req.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")

    dump, err := httputil.DumpRequest(req, true)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("Could not dump request. ", err)
    }

    log.Println("Request: ", string(dump))

    client := http.Client{}
    log.Println("Initiating http request")

    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("HTTP Error: %v", err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    bytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("Error reading response body: %v", err)
    }

    var config config

    err = json.Unmarshal(bytes, &config)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("Could not unamrshal json. ", err)
    }

    return &config, nil
}
```

Comment: One possible approach could be https://play.golang.org/p/DBNHys_OL1j

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say the essence of sending the request is that you are sending a body to an endpoint and parsing a result.  The headers are then optional options that you can add to the request along the way.  With this in mind I would make a single common function for sending the request with this signature:

```
type option func(*http.Request)
func sendRequest(endpoint string, body interface{}, result interface{}, options ...option) error {
```

Note this is using functional options which Dave Cheney did an excellent description of here:

https://dave.cheney.net/2014/10/17/functional-options-for-friendly-apis

The complete code then becomes:

https://play.golang.org/p/GV6FeipIybA

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httputil"
)

type token struct {
    Token string
}

type config struct {
    Foo string
}

func main() {
    token, err := getAuthToken()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    config, err := getConfig("foo", token)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    _ = config
}

func getAuthToken() (string, error) {
    endpoint := "foo"

    body := struct {
        UserName string `json:"username"`
        Password string `json:"password"`
    }{
        UserName: "foo",
        Password: "bar",
    }
    var token token

    err := sendRequest(endpoint, body, &token)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    return token.Token, nil
}

func getConfig(id string, token string) (*config, error) {
    endpoint := "foo"

    body := struct {
        ID string `json:"id"`
    }{
        ID: id,
    }
    var config config

    err := sendRequest(endpoint, body, &config, header("Content-Type", "application/json"))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return &config, nil
}

type option func(*http.Request)
func header(key, value string) func(*http.Request) {
    return func(req *http.Request) {
        req.Header.Add(key, value)
    }
}

func sendRequest(endpoint string, body interface{}, result interface{}, options ...option) error {
    jsnBytes, err := json.Marshal(body)
    if err != nil {
        return err

    }

    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", endpoint, bytes.NewReader(jsnBytes))
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("Unable to create request. %v", err)

    }

    req.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
    for _, option := range options {
        option(req)
    }


    dump, err := httputil.DumpRequest(req, true)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("Could not dump request. ", err)
    }

    log.Println("Request: ", string(dump))

    client := http.Client{}
    log.Println("Initiating http request")

    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("HTTP Error: %v", err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    bytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("Error reading response body: %v", err)
    }

    err = json.Unmarshal(bytes, result)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("Could not unamrshal json. ", err)
    }
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The way I would do this is to extract the two parts that are common to both request executions: 1) create a request and 2) execute the request.

[Gist with new code](https://gist.github.com/visola/5359a3993c4f06d860ff192f1405c490) using HTTP Bin as an example

Creating the request includes setting up the endpoint, headers and marshaling the request body to JSON. In your case, you're also dumping the request to the log, that can also go in there. This is how it would look like:

```
func buildRequest(endpoint string, body interface{}, extraHeaders map[string]string) (*http.Request, error) {
  jsnBytes, err := json.Marshal(body)
  if err != nil {
    return nil, err
  }

  req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", endpoint, bytes.NewReader(jsnBytes))
  if err != nil {
    return nil, err
  }

  req.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")

  for name, value := range extraHeaders {
    req.Header.Add(name, value)
  }

  dump, err := httputil.DumpRequest(req, true)
  if err != nil {
    return nil, err
  }

  log.Println("Request: ", string(dump))

  return req, nil
}
```

If you have no extra headers, you can pass `nil` as the third argument here.

The second part to extract is actually executing the request and unmarshalling the data. This is how the executeRequest would look like:

```
func executeRequest(req *http.Request, responseBody interface{}) error {
    client := http.Client{}
    log.Println("Initiating http request")

    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    bytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    log.Printf("Response is: %s\n", string(bytes))
    err = json.Unmarshal(bytes, &responseBody)
    return err
}
```